# Writing binary to std::fstream using the << operator

Tags: c++

For some reason this sort code is not working as I would expect:

```
std::fstream theFile;
theFile.open(<someFilename>, std::ios::beg |std::ios::out|std::ios::binary|std::ios::trunc);
theFile << 1;          //1 is being written as a string
int var= 25;

theFile << 25;        //same thing, 25 is written as a string
```

What could be the problem? I am using the Microsoft C++ compiler that ships with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<<` operator's whole purpose is to write formatted data to a stream. If you want to write binary data, you should use `ostream::write()` or `ostream::put()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast the values first as a `char`, otherwise the iostream library sees the values as `int` and formats them as a readable string.

```
theFile << (char)1 << (char)25;
```

Comment: @sehe, Yes it will. The file will not care about signed vs. unsigned. It will be written to the file unsigned. I encourage you to try it and see for yourself. I just did and it worked fine. You can write anything from 0 to 255.

Comment: Oh..., my mistake. I must have been blinded by the coincidence that my compiler allows integer beyond 255 too. Negative integers too, for crying out loud.

Comment: Thanks, answers were spot on. Apparently the std::ios::binary switch is only for optimizing file seek operations; ostream << will always write formatted data and ostream::write / ostream::put binary data irrespective of the mode.

Would be cool to be able to write more than one char with the << operator; guess I'll have to inherit from std::fstream and override the operator.