# Sending integer to fstream as little endian

Tags: c++, fstream

I am writting function for create and save WAV file but I don't know how to send numbers to stream:

```
ofstream file;
file.open("sound.wav");
file << "RIFF";
file << (int) 32;
file << "WAVE";
```

I am trying to implement this WAVE file structure: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

and problem is here the output is like this:

```
RIFF32WAVE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The streaming operator `<<` does *formatted* output - it converts values to text. This is not what you want for writing to a binary file format.

Instead, you want to use the *unformatted* output functions: `put` for single bytes, and `write` for multiple bytes:

```
file.write("RIFF", 4);

// The length field is little-endian, so write the lowest byte first
file.put(length);
file.put(length >> 8);
file.put(length >> 16);
file.put(length >> 24);

file.write("WAVE", 4);
```

UPDATE: as noted in the comments, you should also open the file in binary mode and inbue it with the classic "C" locale, to prevent anything from messing around with the bytes you write:

```
file.open("sound.wav", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
file.imbue(std::locale::classic());
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that the file must be opened in binary mode, and imbued with the classic locale.  (Otherwise: it's a pleasure to see someone proposing a clean and correct solution, rather than just a hack which only works with some specific implementations.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Do either of those make a difference to unformatted output? (As a Linux programmer writing code that doesn't need localisation, I've never bothered to learn about those things in detail).

Comment: Yes.  Under Unix, there is no actual difference between binary and text, but in almost all other systems, there is.  And locales other than the classic locale can (and sometimes do) transcode on input and output.  (IMHO, this should also be disabled in binary mode.  But it's not; it's entirely under the control of the imbued locale.)  I don't know, off hand, whether any of the available locales actually do transcode in Unix, but the possibility exists.  (FWIW: there's a function `always_noconv` in `codecvt`; if it returns `true`, you're OK.)

Comment: One additional detail: both the distinction binary/text and the code conversion take place in `std::filebuf`.  Where they have no knowledge of whether the characters come from formatted output or unformatted output.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the explanation, I've added those points to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the file in binary output mode and then print into it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277485/writing-binary-to-stdfstream-using-the-operator) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Stream operators is for formatted I/O (Text), not binary. Take a look at the write method instead. As for the little vs big endian issue, you could simply use the htonl() function provided by your OS.