# C++ write and read two values sequentially from binary file using stream operator

Tags: c++, io, binary

A simple test with binary I/O in C++.
It appears that after writing two values in a row, reading from the same file would concatenate the two numbers.

- In case of two integers, the first integer gets all the values, the second integers remains what it was before (For example, let a = 111, b = 234; the reading results in a = 111234, b = what-ever-old-value)
- In case of two floats, the concatenation is partial, meaning the second float still gets some value, albeit incorrect (For example, let a = 111.1, b = 234.4; the reading results in a = 111.123, b = 0.4).

I know I can use read() and write() functions of file stream to precisely control how many bytes to read, and in that case everything works. But I am just wondering if I should never use << and >>, or I was using them improperly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    int a = 111;
    int b = 234;
    cout << a << '\t' << b << endl; // print 111    234
    // save
    ofstream o("a.bin",ios::out|ios::binary);
    o << a << b;
    o.close();

    // reset to test
    a = -9999;
    b = -9999;
    // load
    ifstream i("a.bin",ios::in|ios::binary);
    i >> a >> b;
    cout << a << '\t' << b << endl; // print 111234    -9999
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Open `a.bin`, it isn't binary. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559254 help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing binary to std::fstream using the << operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277485/writing-binary-to-stdfstream-using-the-operator)