# endl not creating new line in output file

Tags: c++, fileoutputstream, endl

This is my code now

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

// set up input file
ifstream lInput;    // declare an input file variable (object)
ofstream lOutput;
lInput.open(argv[1], ifstream::binary); // open an input file (binary)
lOutput.open(argv[2], ofstream::binary);
if (!lInput.good())
{
    // operation failed
    cerr << "Cannot open input file " << argv[1] << endl;
    return 2;       // program failed (input)
}

lOutput << "test" << endl;
lOutput << "test2" << endl;
```

My current output is

> testtest2

How do I make it to

> test
>
> test2

Thankyou for your help

edit: test to "test" and test2 to "test2"
edit2: lOutpt to lOutput

Comment: It is ALWAYS better to post the actual code you use. That way you remove the typos an undefined stuff that you question now has too much of.

Comment: How are viewing the output file? You could change `lOutput.open(argv[2], ofstream::binary);` to `lOutput.open(argv[2]);` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281481/4926357. Don't use `<<` with binary streams.

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ have two types of files: **text** and **binary**. Binary files are not text. They don't have lines, so they don't have line endings. If you want to talk sensibly about line endings and other **text-related** things, use a **text** file.