# Save an unsigned char vector one by one

Tags: c++, vector, char, unsigned

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Compiler.h"
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream output("file.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    if(output.fail()) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned char> f = Runtime::convert_line_to_instructions("rt_reg str Hello");
    for(unsigned char i : f) {
        //output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>&i, sizeof(unsigned short)); doesn't work here.
    }
    std::cerr << "Program Compiled!" << std::endl;
    while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I save an unsigned char vector to a file? I've tried several solutions (including the one that's commented out), but none of them worked.

*convert_line_to_instructions returns an unsigned char vector too.

Comment: How would you have saved the data if it were a simple array of `unsigned char`?

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned short)` why do use short for the size of a char?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The same really. You can parse arrays with range loops too.

Comment: `output << i;` done

Comment: @manni66 Doesn't seem to work. File size is still 0 bytes.

Comment: @Teytix -- The reason I asked is that if you were successful in using a regular array, using a vector should be little, if any difference.  A vector is just a wrapper around a (dynamic) array.  The answer you accepted is basically `output.write(array, array_length);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `output.put(i);` since it takes one character at a time.

But you really want to skip the for-loop and just write the whole vector in one write:

```
output.write(f.data(), f.size());
```

Comment: File size is still 0 bytes.

Comment: You have an infinite loop at the end of your program, thus you never flush the output to file. So when you abort the program, the data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

It's an fstream, so you can use iostream operators, like `<<`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    std::ofstream output{"file.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc};
    if (output.fail())
        return 1;

    std::vector<unsigned char> input = {'r', 't', '_', 'r', 'e', 'g', ' ',
                                        's', 't', 'r', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l',
                                        'l', 'o'};

    for (const auto i : input)
        output << i;

    return 0;
}
```

A slightly cleaner approach would be to use an STL algorithm with an iterator:

```
std::copy(begin(input), end(input), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(output));
```

The `ostreambuf_iterator<char>` is lightweight, buffered, and performs no formatting.

Comment: Your code won't write `binary` even though you opened the file with `std::ios::binary`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277485/writing-binary-to-stdfstream-using-the-operator

Comment: @Brandon As listed, it indeed does write binary and I have a hex dump to prove it. The problem is that it isn't guaranteed to write binary data, if you mess with the output formatting. If you don't, then it works.